# Combining Cell Data or Rows based on Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Wondering how to transform table to remove redundant rows. See image for desired outcome.

[image]

Comment: Have you followed any one of the solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=LET(rowID;A2:A7;uniID;UNIQUE(rowID);list;B2:B7;result;BYROW(uniID;LAMBDA(currentID;TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER(list;rowID=currentID))));CHOOSE({1\2};uniID;result))
```

Edit as per comment:

- find the unique company names
- filter the column with the related names
- transform array of related names to a string
- combine unique company and string of names

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried and come up with the following multiple approaches,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION_POWER_QUERY]

---

The following formula is applicable to **MS365**

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A7),
contacts,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(B2:B7,A2:A7=a)))),
CHOOSE({1,2},u,contacts))
```

---

Perhaps if you are not using **MS365** then may be using **Excel 2019** then use the below one,

• Formula used in cell `D7` --> To get Unique Company Name,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(D$6:D6,$A$2:$A$7),0)),"")
```

• Formula used in cell `E7` --> To get combined Contact Name in one single cell,

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(B2:B7,A2:A7=D7))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using **Power Query**, available in **Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)** -- **Note** for **Excel 2010 - 2013** you need to download the **[Microsoft Power Query add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39379)** for Excel 2010/2013 (also no longer updated by Microsoft)

Using **Power Query**

• Select any cell in your Data Table,

• Data => **Get & Transform Data** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home => Advanced Editor**

• **Delete** anything shown in the Advanced Editor, also note to change the existing Table Name with the one in M Code or with yours.

• And paste the **M Code** from below,

[image: POWER_QUERY]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Company Name"}, {{"Contact Name", each Text.Combine([Contact Name], ", "), type text}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Company Name", type text}, {"Contact Name", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image: POWER QUERY]

---

However, if you are in **MS365** and when writing the below formula if you have enabled the **Beta Channel** from **Office Insiders**, then using `LAMBDA()` , `BYROW()`, `TAKE()`, `DROP()`, `VSTACK()` & `HSTACK()` use these newer formulas as well,

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(headers,TAKE(array,1),
ComName,DROP(array,1,-1),
ConName,DROP(array,1,1),
u,UNIQUE(ComName),
Cn,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(ConName,ComName=a)))),
VSTACK(headers,HSTACK(u,Cn))))(A1:B7)
```

---

Also note you can use a custom defined, reusable formula with a friendly name,

```
=LISTDATA(A1:B7)
```

---

```
Syntax =LISTDATA(array)
```

---

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(headers,TAKE(array,1),
ComName,DROP(array,1,-1),
ConName,DROP(array,1,1),
u,UNIQUE(ComName),
Cn,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(ConName,ComName=a)))),
VSTACK(headers,HSTACK(u,Cn))))
```

Which is a defined name --> copy the above formula shown above and paste in Refers to:

--> **Formulas Tab** --> **Define Name** --> **Name** --> **LISTDATA** --> **Refers to:**

[image: NAME_MANAGER]

[image: LIST_DATA]

[image]